# Python protobuf converted to json

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to convert message object

```
message = [id: "ff90608b-bb1f-463b-ad26-e0027e67e826"
byte_content: "PK\003\004\024\000\000\000\010\000\360\206\322R\007AMb\201\...00\000\310\031\000\000\000\000"
file_type: "application/pdf"
file_name: "cumulative-essentials-visit.pdf"
]
```

by

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict 
dict_obj = MessageToDict(message_obj)
```

to json but got an error

```
message_descriptor = message.DESCRIPTOR
AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Is there any idea?
Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to convert this message? Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: A similar issue was discussed in [object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70#issuecomment-406194079)

Could you let me know if it helps? If it doesn't please share a short reproducible example.

Comment: I use 
**`from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict`
 `dict_obj = MessageToDict(message_obj)`**
@PirateNinjas

Comment: I had tried but it does still not work @FelixKJose

Comment: @TinVan Are you still facing this issue? Could you provide the message object (*_pb2.py) file, so I could generate a message and try the conversion to dict. 

Also another thing to check is whether you are able to convert any protobuf message to dict/json or do you want an example?

Comment: Hi @FelixKJose! I am not working on it more, but I will come back then try on your solution, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example as well as reproducing the exception above.

Step 1: **todolist.proto** file with following content:

```
syntax = "proto3";

// Not necessary for Python but should still be declared to avoid name collisions 
// in the Protocol Buffers namespace and non-Python languages
package protoblog;

// Style guide prefers prefixing enum values instead of surrounding
// with an enclosing message
enum TaskState {
    TASK_OPEN = 0;
    TASK_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
    TASK_POST_PONED = 2;
    TASK_CLOSED = 3;
    TASK_DONE = 4;
}

message TodoList {
    int32 owner_id = 1;
    string owner_name = 2;

    message ListItems {
        TaskState state = 1;
        string task = 2;
        string due_date = 3;
    }

    repeated ListItems todos = 3;
}
```

Step 2: Generate python specific code from todolist.proto file by running following:

```
protoc -I=. --python_out=. todolist.proto
```

This will generate a file in the current directory **todolist_pb2.py**

Step 3: Create a python project and copy **todolist_pb2.py** to it.

Step 4: Create a python module **proto_test.py** with following content:

```
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from todolist_pb2 import TodoList

todolist_json_message = {
    "ownerId": "1234",
    "ownerName": "Tim",
    "todos": [
        {
            "state": "TASK_DONE",
            "task": "Test ProtoBuf for Python",
            "dueDate": "31.10.2019"
        }
    ]
}


todolist_proto_message = Parse(json.dumps(todolist_json_message), TodoList())
print(todolist_proto_message)

# Successfully converts the message to dictionary
todolist_proto_message_dict = MessageToDict(todolist_proto_message)
print(todolist_proto_message_dict)

# If you try to convert a field from your message rather than entire message,
# you will get object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR exception'
# Examples:
# Eg.1: Produces AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute
# 'DESCRIPTOR.'
todos_as_dict = MessageToDict(todolist_proto_message.todos)

# Eg.2: Produces AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
owner_id_as_dict = MessageToDict(todolist_proto_message.owner_id)
```

Step 5: Run the **proto_test.py** module and you can see the failing behavior and the successful behavior.

So it seems like you are not converting your actual message rather you are converting a field of type list from your message/response. So try to convert the entire message and then retrieve the field you are interested in.

Please let me know if it helps.

**NOTE:** You need to ensure **protoc compiler** is installed in your machine to compile **.proto** file to python specific code as mentioned in step 2.
Installation instruction can be found below:
[MacOS/Linux](http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html)

[Windows](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md#c-installation---windows)

Comment: Hi @FelixKJose! I am not working on it more, but I will come back then try on your solution, thanks for your help.